# Hibernate DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener checking for insert and update database events

Tags: hibernate, spring, event-listener

Using hibernate 3.3.2.ga and Spring 3.0.5.RELEASE.

Have implemented something as described [here](http://notatube.blogspot.com/2010/03/hibernate-using-event-listener-to-set.html)..

with a different config as I;m using a Spring managed sessionFactory

```
<bean id="sessionFactoryPGAD" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourcePGAD"/>
.......
.......
<property name="eventListeners">
    <map>
        <entry key="save-update"><ref local="auditEntityListener" /></entry>
    </map>
</property>
```

to add auditing when my DAOs call

```
...getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(...
```

However in my extended DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener (bean named auditEntityListener) I was wondering if there is any way to determine if the object being saved to the db is a new record or an update to one that exists?

I've tried looking at

```
EntityEntry entityEntry = event.getEntry();
if (entityEntry.isExistsInDatabase())
{.....
```

but entityEntry is null for an entity I know exists in the db.

Other methods on SaveOrUpdateEvent like getRequestedId() and getResultId() also return null.

How could I determine if the hibernate call will be a insert or update from the DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener?

Answer (score 0):

The method you're looking for is [getEntityState()](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/javadoc/org/hibernate/event/def/AbstractSaveEventListener.html#getEntityState%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20org.hibernate.engine.EntityEntry,%20org.hibernate.engine.SessionImplementor%29). Here's an example of its use taken from the source code for DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener:

```
int entityState = getEntityState(
    event.getEntity(),
    event.getEntityName(),
    event.getEntry(),
    event.getSession()
);

switch ( entityState ) {
    case DETACHED:
        entityIsDetached( event );
        return null;
    case PERSISTENT:
        return entityIsPersistent( event );
    default: //TRANSIENT or DELETED
        return entityIsTransient( event );
}
```

If you need to do something different for save versus update, you might want to consider having separate EventListeners, one that extends DefaultSaveEventListener and one that extends DefaultUpdateEventListener, and allow Hibernate to dispatch to the correct listener for you.

Comment: thanks for that - I did initially have 2 listeners listening for pre-insert and pre-update events(using the interfaces provided) but the event listeners din't get any events as only the save-update event was being fired as my DAO calls .getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(...

how would I get hibernate to dispatch to the correct listener if the only event is a save-update event...?

Comment: Also calling getEntityState(event.getEntity(),  event.getEntityName(), event.getEntry(), event.getSession()) does not work as event.getEntry() throws a NPE as it did when checking for if (entityEntry.isExistsInDatabase()) as mentioned above.........

Comment: Not seeing all your code for context, it sounds like your entity might be detached at the time you're calling the saveOrUpdate. Check out the source code for getEntityState() to see how it works: http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/hibernate/event/def/AbstractSaveEventListener.java.html